# on importing csv file data into mysql table getting garbage value

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I want to import 5 gb of records which is in csv file(pincode.csv) into mysql table in particular column (pincode,city and state) .

Given below is my csv file

```
504293,Asifabad,ANDHRA PRADESH
504231,Luxettipet,ANDHRA PRADESH
504201,Chennur,ANDHRA PRADESH
504295,Asifabad,ANDHRA PRADESH
```

and table structure is

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| pincode | int(10)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| city    | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state   | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I tried code given below

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=0 --fields-terminated-by=,
 --columns='pincode,city,state' --local -u root -p 
   --default_character_set utf8 pincode_db pincode.csv
```

after running this command its importing only 2 fields which is some garbage value.

Comment: Can you post more code please

Comment: Also show your csv file and your table so that we can help you out with it

Comment: i tried this code only    mysqlimport --ignore-lines=0 --fields-terminated-by=,
 --columns='pincode,city,state' --local -u root -p 
   pincode_db /path/to/pincode.csv

Comment: Can you show your table and a bit of the csv?

Comment: Edit your question add the csv file and your table so that it's easier readable.

Comment: Please have a look i elaborated my problem

Comment: A thing that you have mentioned is that you have 5gb of the csv file which means that the int(10) for id wont be able to handle so much id.Try to change the int from 10 to 255 and add Unsigned to is which will remove the nagative value from it.If that doesn't work try to use BIGINT instead.

Comment: The max value of int(4 bytes) unsigned is 4294967295.For big int its 18446744073709551615

Comment: Also try to do it with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ‘path…’ INTO TABLE language(name);

Comment: okk i have another file of same record of 4.3MB

Comment: i tried but not workable

Comment: What response do you get when you add it?

Comment: am getting some chinese sort of character for city and state

Comment: Agree with @Arslan.H to use LOAD DATA INFILE - and depending how the file was created (and what app) you may have to try different values for how carriage returns (next lines) are handled.

Comment: I also tried      load data local infile 'pincode.csv' into table pincode fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\r\n' (pincode,city,state);    getting error   "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version"   mysql version:-  5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/database_name/filename.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE pincode_tmp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (pincode,city,state);  ------------------> thanks  this solution worked for me

Comment: Please add an answer below - code or solutions in comments are not very readable.